# Selenium RemoteWebDriver get alert text causes ClassCastException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-grid, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have Selenium Grid running locally. I run a test that should check if an alert is shown. While running without Selenium Grid the test passes. But when I run the same test on a local Grid instance I receive a ClassCastException

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

The exception is thrown on this method call

```
 driver.switchTo().alert();
```

I see that RemoteWebDriver executes command `DriverCommand.GET_ALERT_TEXT`.
So my question is how to check if an alert is present while running on Selenium Grid?

Comment: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/931

Answer (score 0):

C# sample:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, DefaultTimeout)
 .Until(ExpectedConditions.AlertIsPresent())
 .Accept();
```

Maybe you can find something similar in Java!?